# Validation Rule

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I am a bit lost on how to complete this validation rule.

If a user chooses "Yes" from the picklist, I would like a reminder (error message) to appear at the bottom of the field advising them to check another object before continuing. I know this can be done with an apex trigger but I am not confident yet to create one.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( $ObjectType.Plan__c.Fields.Uses_Transit__c , "YES")
```

Reminder (Error Message): Check the Current Fiscal Year IRS/DOL Limits for Annual and Monthly Limits. [image]

I am getting a syntax error. I am not sure what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The current error is for missing ')', however you are not using the correct syntax of the function here as well.

Answer (score 2):

With an If statement, you need 3 values, the condition to test, a value if it's true, and a value if it's false. If what you're looking to find out is whether or not the value of that pickval is "yes", then just use:

```
ispickval(fielname,"Yes")
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a little confused on filename portion of the formula. I currently have (ISPICKVAL( $ObjectType.Plan__c.Fields.Uses_Transit__c , "Yes")
)

Comment: I used (ISPICKVAL(Uses_Transit__c , "Yes") 
) But, I now receive "Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data" as well as my error message. Error: Check the Current Fiscal Year IRS/DOL Limits for Annual and Monthly Limits. I choose yes but the page will not save.

Comment: I've read your exchange with @JennyB. It sounds as though you may want to rethink your logic/approach to using this field as an indicator that something isn't correct in the data from this related object. A validation rule doesn't seem to be the correct way to handle it. Some other business logic would seem to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

That error just means you are missing a closing parenthesis on one of your functions...

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( $ObjectType.Plan__c.Fields.Uses_Transit__c , "YES")
```

`IF()` // should have an open and close
`ISPICKVAL()` // should have an open and close

but your formula is incomplete, an IF statement requires a result for when it is true and when it is false. Since you are creating a validation rule you really do not need the IF statement just the `ISPICKVAL($ObjectType.Plan__c.Fields.Uses_Transit__c , "YES")`

UPDATE: After reading your requirements again, I don't think a validation rule is what you are looking for because it will not be a warning it will be an error and not let the user continue. I would suggest using a formula to create a reminder on the screen or perhaps javascript to throw out a popup message.

Comment: Thank you Jenny. When I use (ISPICKVAL( $ObjectType.Plan__c.Fields.Uses_Transit__c , "YES")
) I get "Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Object"

Comment: @SynthiaBeauvais Didn't notice the $ObjectType, use the formula insert field functionality to find the field to evaluate.

Comment: @SBeauvais34 updated my answer, I'm not sure using a validation rule will help you achieve your goal.

Comment: I was afraid of that. The field is not mandatory so I just need the error message to populate once the field is being used (Yes is chosen). Thank you.

Comment: I used (ISPICKVAL(Uses_Transit__c , "Yes") 
) But, I now receive "Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data" as well as my error message. Error: Check the Current Fiscal Year IRS/DOL Limits for Annual and Monthly Limits. I choose Yes from the picklist but the page will not save.

Comment: @SBeauvais34 a validation rule will prevent save whenever your formula evaluates to true, so if you want it to error when it is not yes place your formula inside NOT ()

Comment: I used ISPICKVAL(Uses_Transit__c , "NOT Yes") but the error message does not come up at all.

Comment: @SBEAUVAIS34 NOT(ISPICKVAL(Uses_Transit__c , "Yes") )

Comment: Thank you Jenny. That doesn't pop up the error message. I will have to figure out a way to write a trigger :-( Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: I would like to try a different approach but I am getting a syntax error Extra 'NOT'. Basically if yes is chosen then Field Transit Annual Limit Must have a dollar amount before saving. IF(ISPICKVAL(Uses_Transit__c , "Yes") )
NOT(ISBLANK( Fields.Transit_Annual_Limit__c ))

Comment: Nevermind. I used AND ( 
ISPICKVAL(Uses_Transit__c , "Yes"), 
ISBLANK( Transit_Annual_Limit__c ) 
) I was able to place my error message and advised the user to fill in the appropriate fields.